# Cannot get my GRAPHQL response into an iterable JSON format

Tags: javascript, php, graphql, fetch

so a bit of background. I am making a GRAPHQL call to shopify's graphQL api. I am getting data back (yay!) and it is correct (double yay!!), unfortunately I cannot then do very much with the data other than look at it - I cannot iterate through it with regular JSON syntax. My plan is to then have the data be put into javascript generated HTML elements to display to the user e.g. generate a list with the titles/pictures of the products.

Without further ado, my code.

Step 1: a JS function to respond to my keypresses and run an async fetch:

```
function ajaxProductSearch(shopCode){
    let devSearch = document.getElementById('product_search_dev');
    devSearch.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
        shopCode = document.querySelector(".langTab.active input").value;
        showGraphQL(shopCode, devSearch.value);
    });
}
```

Step 2: my async fetch call to the php script

```
async function showGraphQL(shopCode, search){
    const response = await fetch(`../models/ajaxcall.php?shop=${shopCode}&searchString=${search}`);
    const graphQL = await response.json();
     console.log(graphQL);
}
```

Step 3: my php script itself running the graphQL call, done with curl

```
3a: The curl function
```

```
function graphQLCall($qry, $endpoint, $flag=''){
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/graphql';
        $headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: '.$authToken;

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_Header, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        
        $graphQL = json_decode($result);
        if($flag == ''){
            return $graphQL;
        } elseif($flag == 'flag'){
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

3b: the code that preps the query for the graphQL func
$query1 uses the $_POST[] to get the $searchString from the front end to the backend

```
        $query1 = '{
  products(first: 25, query: "title:'.$searchString.'") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}';
$mediaID = graphQLCall($query1, $endpoint);
```

$query1 is passed through the graphQLCall() and then its response, which is the id of the product is then passed into a 2nd query to then call the product itself:
3b of the php script:

```
    foreach($mediaID->data->products->edges as $a){
        // echo $a->node->id;
            $query2 = '{
  product(id: "'.$a->node->id.'") {
    id
    title
    images(first:1) {
      edges {
       node {
         originalSrc
         id
       }
      }
    }  
  }
}';         
            array_push($graphQLArray, $query2);
        }
```

It then pushes the response into an array, so I am left with an array full of queries with the correct product id. Next that array is iterated through in order to call the products themselves.
4b of php script:

```
$restCallArray = array();
    foreach($graphQLArray as $t){
        array_push($restCallArray, graphQLCall($t, $endpoint, "flag"));
    }
    $json = json_encode($restCallArray);
    print_r($json);
```

The final step in my php script is to `print_r($json);`

after which it is then processed by my async showGraphQL() function; written above.

My async fetch responds with something like this when I post to innerHTML:

```
{"data":{"product":{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/6736442654756","title":"Cactus Sneaker Women","images":{"edges":[{"node":{"originalSrc":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0009\/8421\/9684\/products\/76-10-49321-548_1.jpg?v=1631627733","id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/28632222433316"}}]}}},"extensions":{"cost":{"requestedQueryCost":4,"actualQueryCost":4,"throttleStatus":{"maximumAvailable":2000.0,"currentlyAvailable":1996,"restoreRate":100.0}}}},{"data":{"product":{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/6736442687524","title":"Cactus Sneaker Men","images":{"edges":[{"node":{"originalSrc":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0009\/8421\/9684\/products\/76-10-49322-548_1.jpg?v=1631627827","id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/28632226070564"}}]}}},"extensions":{"cost":{"requestedQueryCost":4,"actualQueryCost":4,"throttleStatus":{"maximumAvailable":2000.0,"currentlyAvailable":1996,"restoreRate":100.0}}}}
```

The above response is totally correct but, the problem occurs when I try to place it in a html element like: `graphQL[i].data.product.id` I receive `undefined`.
That is my problem that I am unable to correctly iterate through what appears to be a JSON.

I am new to graphQL and to using API's in general so appreciate any help and apologize that its so longwinded, I hope the question/problem is clear and that the code is presented clearly too.

- Boogabooga

Comment: Not clear if you are going to process this in PHP or JS?

Comment: Hi, so I want to do the graphQL call itself with php, and then process the response in JS. So my plan is to have my async graphQL() function process the response into HTML elements for the user.

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/fetch-with-json/

Comment: At what point do you receive `undefined`, what reference? Also, show the full response JSON because what you have shown is not an array but an object.

Comment: Hi there, so I receive `undefined` when I try to call a specific point from the response of my php script e.g. in my `async graphQL()` function. So when I call `graphQL[i].data.product.id` it is `undefined` I will update the question to the full JSON response

Comment: the last code indented part of my question is now the full response I get from my PHP script, displayed via my `async graphQL` function.
In my php script I `json_encode` the array before printing it, because if I do not do that I receive a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0` message

Comment: So this `graphQL[i].data.product.id` looks wrong because `graphQL` is an object not an array and the object has no zero `0` key. Of course this is based on the JSON you show in your question. Have you tried `graphQL.data.product.id`?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, so when I try to do `graphQL.data.product.id` it returns undefined. 
The reason I was then putting it through a `graphQL[i]` loop is because my PHP script first pushes the responses from the `graphQL` into an `array` and then `json_encode()` is run on the array, all in the php script.

Comment: so, in my JS function `graphQL()` when I call `response.text()` rather than `response.json()` AND in my php script I call `print_r($restCallArray);` and remove the `json_encode($restCallArray)` I receive this in my `console.log`

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => {"data":{"product":{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/6736442654756","title":"Cactus Sneaker Women","images":{"edges":[{"node":{"originalSrc":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0009\/8421\/9684\/products\/76-10-49321-548_1.jpg?v=1631627733","id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/28632222433316"}}]}}},"extensions":{"cost":{"requestedQueryCost":4,"actualQueryCost":4,"throttleStatus":{"maximumAvailable":2000.0,"currentlyAvailable":1996,"restoreRate":100.0}}}}` 
There is a [1] but I had to omit it because of character length, my point being I am able to get an array

Comment: but as soon as I either try to call `json` functions on it in either PHP or JS, I start getting `syntax unexpected charracter in line x` errors, sorry for all the comments haha :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case anyone finds this later and runs into the same problem. Going off of what @morganney said, I was receiving an Object. So by my logic, which is not the logic you want to lead you into battle but whatever, I need to parse this object into a JSON using `JSON.parse()` so. I did NOT change my PHP script but rather my JS `async graphQL()`
**This is my edited async GraphQL() func**

```
async function showGraphQL(shopCode, search){
    const response = await fetch(`../models/ajaxcall.php?shop=${shopCode}&searchString=${search}`);
    const graphQL = await response.json();
     for(let i = 0; i < graphQL.length; i++){
         let graphQLJSON = JSON.parse(graphQL[i]);
         console.log(graphQLJSON.data.product.id);
     }
}
```

Confusingly, I loop through my `graphQL` variable, and call `JSON.parse(graphQL[i])` on it, I am then able to console.log specific values of the now JSON.

I hope this helps someone someday and thanks to the people who commented.

- Boogabooga

Comment: The right track for me, I had to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))`